# jQuery click and onload in one function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 jQuery function that work as click and onload. Is this possible to create as one function only so I will not repeat the function?

`$("[name$='radioGroup1'], [name$='radioGroup2']").on('click load', function() {}`

Using "on" like the above code is not working for me.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="123.radioGroup1" class="">
<input type="checkbox" name="123.radioGroup1" class="">
<input type="checkbox" name="123.radioGroup1" class="">

<input type="checkbox" name="123.radioGroup2" class="">
<input type="checkbox" name="123.radioGroup2" class="">
<input type="checkbox" name="123.radioGroup2" class="">
```

```
$("[name$='radioGroup1'], [name$='radioGroup2']").click(function() {
  var thisGroup = this.name;
    $('input[name="'+thisGroup+'"]').each(function() {
        if($('input[name="'+thisGroup+'"]').is(':checked') == true){
          $('input[name="'+thisGroup+'"]').css("box-shadow", "none");
        } else {
          $('input[name="'+thisGroup+'"]').css("box-shadow", "0 0 4px 0 red");
        }
       });
  });

  $("[name$='radioGroup1'], [name$='radioGroup2']").each( function() {
  var thisGroup = this.name;
    $('input[name="'+thisGroup+'"]').each(function() {
        if($('input[name="'+thisGroup+'"]').is(':checked') == true){
          $('input[name="'+thisGroup+'"]').css("box-shadow", "none");
        } else {
          $('input[name="'+thisGroup+'"]').css("box-shadow", "0 0 4px 0 red");
        }
       });
  });
```

Comment: Yes, put the code in a declared function and refer that function in `on` parameter.

Comment: I need html for my check

Comment: @AgungPanduan I have updated the html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use css, and js and html when render

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
    var thisGroup = this.name;  
    if($(this).prop('checked')){
        $('input[name="'+thisGroup+'"]').addClass('checked');
    } else {
        if ($('input[name="'+thisGroup+'"]:checked').length === 0)  {
         $('input[name="'+thisGroup+'"]').removeClass('checked');
        }
    }
});
```

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px 0 red;
}
input[type="checkbox"].checked {
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="123.radioGroup1" class="radioGroup1">
<input type="checkbox" name="123.radioGroup1" class="radioGroup1">
<input type="checkbox" name="123.radioGroup1" class="radioGroup1">

<input type="checkbox" name="123.radioGroup2" class="radioGroup2">
<input type="checkbox" name="123.radioGroup2" class="radioGroup2">
<input type="checkbox" name="123.radioGroup2" class="radioGroup2">

<!-- checked class add when render your html -->
<input type="checkbox" name="123.radioGroup3" class="radioGroup3 checked" checked>
<input type="checkbox" name="123.radioGroup3" class="radioGroup3 checked">
<input type="checkbox" name="123.radioGroup3" class="radioGroup3 checked">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

- Define the process as function
- Group the radio by a `<div>` or something else and bind 'click' event. (so you have only 2 event listener, instead of 6)
- Style the content input elements by css (so you don't have to initialize them)
- Add/Remove another class to the group element (so you don't have to add/remove class to all elements in group).

```js
const fnX = function() {
    var thisGroup = this.id;
    var flag = $('input[name="'+thisGroup+'"]').is(':checked');
    $(this).toggleClass("radiocheck", flag);
}

$("span[class*='radioGroup']").click(fnX);
```

```css
.radioGroup > input {
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px 0 red
}
.radioGroup.radiocheck > input {
  box-shadow: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="radioGroup" id="123.radioGroup1">
<input type="checkbox" name="123.radioGroup1" class="">
<input type="checkbox" name="123.radioGroup1" class="">
<input type="checkbox" name="123.radioGroup1" class="">
</span>
<span class="radioGroup" id="123.radioGroup2">
<input type="checkbox" name="123.radioGroup2" class="">
<input type="checkbox" name="123.radioGroup2" class="">
<input type="checkbox" name="123.radioGroup2" class="">
</span>
```